# Openshift how to validate file before saving into app-root/data

Tags: python, imagemagick, cgi, openshift

I'm trying to find a way to use the function "identify" from imagemagick without saving the image file in app-root/data. Basically I want to validate the image file before actually saving the file into the destination. If saved into app-root/data, i can easily just do this:

```
(temp, tempError) = (subprocess.Popen(['identify', '../data/' + filename + extension], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)).communicate()
```

But this would require the image to be uploaded first before identifying. Any ways to do this?

Comment: I'm afraid that this question strikes me as somewhat vague.  You've not indicated the image formats that you're interested in nor what constitutes validation.  PNG and, I assume, many other formats include the information that `identify` uses at the beginning of the image file in a header.  So one solution might entail grabbing enough of the file to get the header and using `identify` in this fragment.  I'd not call that validation, as one could easily fool such a test with a fake header.

Answer (score 0):

You should save the file into the /tmp directory first, then validate it, and if it passes, then move it to your ~/app-root/data directory.

You can check out this Filesystem Overview on the Developer Portal for more information: https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-filesystem.html